# ReactJS - ExportCSV

Tags: reactjs

In ReactJS, I am using an ExportCSV button to download data into CSV format. How do I pop an alert to prevent the download of empty CSV when the bootstrap table is empty? Currently, when the selection does not retrieve any data, I am still able to download the file with empty contents. Let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

```
<ToolkitProvider
    bootstrap4
    keyField="TIMESTAMP,VALUE"
    data={tData}
    columns={columns}
    className="mt-4 col-md-2 col-offset-4"
    filter={filterFactory()}
    exportCSV={{
      fileName: "Details.csv",
      onlyExportFiltered: true,
    }}
  >
    {(props) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <BootstrapTable
          {...props.baseProps}
          pagination={pagination}
          filter={filterFactory()}
        />
        <ExportCSVButton className="btn btn-success" {...props.csvProps}>
          Export to CSV
        </ExportCSVButton>
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
  </ToolkitProvider>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selection information in a state. If the state size is equivalent to 0, You can display an alert showing that the selection is empty and prevent the user from downloading the CSV.

Comment: Thank you.. I am new to ReactJS.. can you please share high level steps to do this.

Comment: Can u share the code, Without looking at the code, I can't exactly tell u what to do

Comment: You can edit the question, In the edit the question screen, you can put your js code in the question, Not in the comment section.

Comment: Your code is not very clear in the comment section